# MonoTouch - type load exception, updated program not registered in simulator

Tags: iphone, exception, xamarin.ios, osx-snow-leopard, monodevelop

I've installed trial version of MonoTouch, and I'm evaluating it for use.

This strange error has occurred:

> Could not load 'MyProductName' for registration. This could be due to
>   an outdated assembly kept by the simulator, location: /PathToMyProduct

Followed by:

> A type load exception has occurred.

My guess is that, somehow some assembly is not up to date. So I've tried to remove it from the given path. But still it's there. So I performed a purge (reinstalled MonoTouch, removed binary build path, in simulator path, uninstalled from simulator, reset simulator, and finally restarted the OSX). But still it's there.

Any hints on how to solve this peculiar problem?

regards,
Kate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a sleepless night and 24 hour streak, I've finally figured it out! There was an abstract class, and this descendant class doesn't implemented its method. So whenever this class was mentioned in a code, it caused a type load exception. There was no warning in MonoDevelop, it compiled fine, it run fine, it crashed terribly. That's madness! I've implemented the override on this abstracted method, and voilà, it now works as nothing happened. This is possibly a MonoDevelop error, but it also could be in some special iPhone compiler. So be aware of that. This is a simplied situation:

```
    public abstract class Parent : UITableViewDataSource
    {
        ..fields/constructors/methods and things

        // one method overriden just fine
        public override Int32 RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, Int32 section)
        {
            return SomeReasonableResult;
        }

        // other one is made abstract, and passed to descendants
        public abstract override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath);
    }
```

Now later on descendant class:

```
    public class Child : Parent
    {
        // GetCell method not implemented! No error or warning in compiler, or run log!
        // but when mentioned in a different class (for example) it crashes.
    }
```

Maybe it's a known behavior or limitation. But still madness.

I'm going to sleep now...

Comment: Note: Obviously it's primarily my mistake. That I've missed the override, but nevertheless there should've been some kind of check. Seriously :)

Comment: I just tried added some abstract method to a base class of mine and got the expected error from the compiler. Then I noticed the `abstract override` in your code (uncommon) but that also caused the compiler error in my code. However your above code *does* compile and throw a `TypeLoadException`.

Comment: Very weird indeed. So I'm really "lucky" to hit that one class that does this. :D

Comment: bug report filled @ https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3647 thanks for providing the test case!

Comment: Thanks for the test case! Also please mark this as the accepted answer (it's ok on stackoverflow to accept our own answers) as it makes it easier for people, when searching, when they see an answer is available.

Comment: weird, don't you see the outline of a checkmark below the upvotes ? it should turn green if you move over it and confirm the question as answered once clicked.

Comment: I know. But it says when clicked: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow (click on this box to dismiss)"

Answer (score 2):

That message *covered* most of the cases where such an exception *occurred*. This was *fixed* (actually we worked around the simulator bug) in MonoTouch 5.0+ (even earlier but I don't recall exactly which version). Simply resetting the simulator is enough to fix this condition.

However this is unlikely the situation you're facing since you did a lot more than what would have been required.

My *guess* would be that the project includes an assembly that refers to types that are not available in MonoTouch (e.g. from `System.Reflection.Emit`) or compiled against a different version of the framework (e.g. reusing an assembly binary compiled against .NET 4.0). However both cases do not *generally* lead to this error message so it could be something else.

It will be hard to further diagnose the problem without having the binaries. Could you either open a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com (you can mark the attachment as private) or send an email to support@xamarin.com (with the project attached) ?

Comment: Hi, the project is created in mono only. It only references monotouch, System, and System.Core. It worked for a while. It still works for few ViewCtrls (even newly programmed things appear in them). However one of the views doesn't work. I'm able to steer away from the type load error, by commenting specific lines (essential though), but I can't link it to a cause other than that the obj-c package is not updated for this view only. The only think weird that happened was that during running a debug session an update to MonoDevelop (or Mono, or Monotouch, I didn't really remember) happened.

Comment: Unfortunately the project is commercial, and I'm testing whether it will be possible to use MonoTouch version (instead of going Xcode/Obj-c) route. I've ported too much (about 60% of the product from WP7), to be able to send you a binary. Is there some other place to check, or option/setting to refresh/reset. As I said it seems, that only one ViewController seems to be unupdated (even though new things do appear in it). Can we solve this without me posting a binary? Thanks

Comment: The versions of products I use are the latest versions: MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5, MonoFramework 2.10.8, MonoTouch 2.1.

Comment: Start with a bug report. Add a link to this question (so you don't have to repeat yourself) and, if possible, show us the code you have to comment to make it work - that *could be* enough of an hint to solve it.

Comment: Hi again, I've already found out. Is that a well known behavior either in MonoDevelop or MonoTouch?

Comment: I don't know what you found ;-) but that error has not been reported for many months (since we worked around the simulator bug). Please fill a bug report (if well/already known then it will be merged with an existing bug report but you'll be sure it won't get unnoticed)

Comment: I've posted an answer ^^ that big chunk of text above your answer.

Comment: But if you're on some aggregator reader or something. It basically is not implemented "abstract override" method on a descendant class, which got compiled fine (no warnings/errors), run fine, but (logically) crashes when touched from somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry I missed it. Clicking on my new messages get me directly to them and my screen is not high enough to show even my own answer. It looks like a compiler bug (not one I recall of, but I could have missed it).

Comment: No problem, check out the described situation. I didn't tested whether it happens at any situation like this, or just in my particular situation, but my guess would be that a check is needed, but missing. Hopefully, some other poor souls will be spared the search (slow deconstruction of project to find out exactly what is the cause).